# Replace double quotes inside other double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, regex, replace, match

I have the next string:

```
{"hexId":"123","version":5,""userAgent":"Mozilla/5.02.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; SM-G935S Build/NRD90M)|||sDid::ba83f40b-22e0-3992-a4d4-15b5d554790c|sAgkey::""|sAppkey::""|null|null|svcode::1221|sgIdKey::1631f8d9-3c1c-4020-a322-53f266ec9547","referer":"http://www.google.com.ar"}
```

When i try to parsing to a JSON (JSON.parse), i get an error because that:

```
sAgkey::""|sAppkey::""
```

So, how can i replace a double quote inside other double quote for a single quote?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't try workarounds. Spend your time on creating a valid json string.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I would love to. But I receive the information from an external app

Comment: You should still focus some effort trying to get it fixed in the external app; even it's not your direct responsibility, just from what you've posted it's clear to see that it urgently needs fixing. The kind of error on display here means that it likely has severe security vulnerabilities. Contact the vendor and get them to fix it before those vulnerabilities get exploited, because if you're taking data from their API then an exploit on their system could easily become an exploit in yours.

Comment: (as an aside, this isn't the first time I've seen a question like this here; I don't get it -- creating a valid JSON stream is utterly trivial in every single language you can name. It's actually harder work to create invalid JSON. So why are so many APIs broken this way??)